# How can I edit web.config to have a different MIME type for a single XML file not others?

Tags: security, iis-7, website, flash, mime

I am trying to set the MIME type for [Flash's cross domain file](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/12413/396) in web.config.  Since this file has an extension of .XML the following command will edit the MIME type of all XML documents in my site (not wanted)

```
  <system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="xml" mimeType="text/x-cross-domain-policy"/>
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

How do I make this only affect the one file, crossdomain.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web.config file at that location, something like:

```
<location path="crossdomain.xml">
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clear />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="text/x-cross-domain-policy" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Would be my guess.

(Tales From Behind The Curtain)
That's a slight variation on what the UI does, which is worth explaining because it's not easily discoverable - to edit a setting for a particular file but not the folder, you can go to the **Content** view tab in that folder, then pick the file you're interested in, *right-click it* and choose Features View. That targets just that file (as can be confirmed in the pane at the left, and in the status bar when you're editing a feature).

It Removed and Add -ed the type, but I find that fragile, so I put a Clear in there instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm seeing security guidance that says this [in combination with a crossdomain.xml file](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/12413/396) will prevent XSS from user uploads & Flash